# How do I properly set up Google Analytics to track conversions that start on my landing pages on a subdomain to the checkout page?

Tags: google-analytics, tracking, shopify

This is the current set up:

- I have a landing page hosted on a subdomain dedicated to landing
  pages (ex. *lp.mysite.com/product-01* and *lp.mysite.com/product-02*).
- Each landing page has a *Buy Now* button, which links to
  *mysite.com/cart/**01**?discount=freeshipping* with **01** being the product number.
- This link redirects the visitor to the checkout page at *checkout.shopify.com/{string}* and adds both the product and the discount code.

It wouldn't be enough to simply set the conversion goal to be the destination path of *mysite.com/cart/**01**?discount=freeshipping* since I want to track sales, which means I need to track the user when he is redirected to the checkout page **and also after** they've completed payment. For Shopify, funnel tracking is done by tracking the thank you page which is shown after payment. [Link](https://docs.shopify.com/support/other/general-information/google-analytics-goals-and-funnels)

My question is: How do I properly set up Google Analytics to track conversions that start on my landing pages on a subdomain to the checkout page?

Comment: The landing pages are not part of Shopify. I coded them from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

If you can add GA code to your landing pages as well, do so. In your GA property settings, set the subdomain tracking, and you should be able to track the entire transaction from the landing pages.

Alternatively, if you cannot add GA code to your landing pages, manually add UTM parameters to the landing page button and track that traffic on your GA. The disadvantage of this approach is that you cannot track the originating traffic source (since that will show up with your UTM parameters now!). However, this could be addressed if you are tracking clicks on your landing pages.